# jquery storing elems to vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a list of `<select>` tags, 22 in total. I use `.find('className');` to store them all in array and then loop through them to get the value of each.

The question is how do I do it exactly with jquery only? Because if I try to use `.val()` on item that's already been stored in variable, I will get the error `.val() is not a function`. So what happens to an element once it's been stored to var? Right now it looks like this:

```
var foo = $('.products_container').find('.fn_variant option:selected');
```

all selected options. Each looks like -

```
<option selected="selected" value="13855" data-price="5 600" data-city_id="5" data-stock="65" data-multiplicity="1">
</option>
```

loop code:

```
for(f in foo) {
    if (typeof foo[f] == 'object') {
        console.log(foo[f].dataset.city_id); 
        // this is the way i'm accessing values right now, which is inconvenient and unclear.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to loop over the selection using jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var $foo = $('.products_container').find('.fn_variant option:selected');
```

and:

```
$foo.each(function(){
    let $cityID = $(this).attr('data-city_id');
});
```

Comment: I'd go with `$(this).data("city_id")` for efficiency and it will pick up any changes such as `$(this).data("city_id", 10)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this, but thanks anyway
https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-loop-select-options/

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers